# How do you shut down games in Origin?

Tags: technical-issues, origin

I just recently installed Sims 3 a month ago but it won't let me on. when I click on my Sims3 window it loads for a while and sometimes nothing comes up but other times there is a sign from Origin that says "You must close all of your active games before playing this one"

When I go to Origin I click on the Sims3 icon and the play button wont work.  So How do you shut down games in Origin?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the game's process is still running in the background but somehow crashed (or something else. The thing is that it decided to take a nap in a corner of your computer). The only solution is to force the process to stop.

Open the Task manager (use the shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+ESCAPE) and open the process tab. Find the process for the game and stop it (you can just select it and press the delete key on your keyboard if you are too lazy to click the button :P I can tell you I am too lazy to click it!).

Once this has been done, try launching the game again. if it doesn't works, close Origin and follow the same steps.

If it still doesn't work, restart your computer.

If all else fails, contact EA Support.